# How to find the intersection of two geodataframes in pandas?

Tags: r, python-3.x, geospatial, arcgis, geopandas

Some Info on my work:

1. I have a shape file with county's soil ssurgo data exported from ARC GIS. It is read into a GeoDataFrame (Gdf1).
2. I have a shape file with boundaries for a farm's individual fields exported from SMS AgLeader. It has been read as DataFrame and converted into GeoDataFrame (Gdf2).

When I perform subplots:

```
aa = Gdf1.plot()
Gdf2.plot(ax=aa)
```

I can see that the Gdf2 falls inside Gdf1.

This is where I am stuck:

I am trying to replicate a "crop" function from R. Python seems to have "overlay" function that is supposed to work, but my code never completes running. Overlay is either overSlow or just doesn't work in this case (confusion, not a statement annnnnnnd the point of my frustration).

## Example of R code (that works):

```
result <- crop(Gdf1, Gdf2)
```

## Example of Python code that never completes executing:

```
result = overlay(Gdf1, Gdf2, how='intersection')
```

## Other attempts that I am not sure of:

*1. result = Gdf1.geometry.intersects(Gdf2.geometry) # result.plot() produces a plot with a horizontal line.

*2. result = Gdf1[Gdf1.within(Gdf2)] # result.plot() gives error: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".

*3. result = Gdf1['geometry'] & Gdf2['geometry'] # result.plot() produces a blank plot.

Comment: The bad performance of the `overlay` is currently a know issue. There is some work on this, and here you can see a possible new implementation posted that you could try out: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/338#issuecomment-290303715

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Simply replacing "overlay" with "spatial_overlays" function gave me what I needed. It is still very slow when I iterate plot over individual fields, but at least I know it works now.

# The code that worked:

    result = spatial_overlays(Gdf1, Gdf2, how='intersection')

    result.plot()

Answer (score 0):

As Joris said in the comments, the bad performance of overlay is well known issue.
However this is particularly bad only for the 'intersect' operation.

If you can get away with using 'within' or 'contains' I would give them a try. They are much faster in the current implementation.

The main difference between within/contain and intersect is the way they treat boundaries. From the documentation:

> intersect
> returns True if if the boundary and interior of each object intersects in any way with those of the other.
>
> within
> returns True if each object’s boundary and interior intersect only with the interior of the other (not its boundary or exterior). (Inverse of contains())

In addition to this, your additional attempt number two can be fixed by:

```
result = Gdf1.loc[Gdf1.within(Gdf2)]
```